# How can I open a file that results from grep?

Tags: bash, grep

I often grep a bunch of files to find a line, and then grep returns one result. Rather than copying and pasting the filename into a new command, I'd like to be able to open that one result with an editor. Something like: `grep foo | vim`. Is there a way to do that in BASH?

Comment: You were rather close, simply tell `vim` to read from `STDIN`: `grep foo | vim -`

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110146/22565

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `grep -l` to just get the filename of the matching file and not the matching text, then combine it with `vim`:

```
vim "$(grep -l some_pattern file_names)"
```

Comment: Additionally, you can use `-q` flag of `grep` to make sure grep has indeed resulted in some matching file: `grep -q patterns fnames && vim $(grep -l pattern fnames)`

Comment: Should I make a remark about filenames with spaces?

Comment: @Bernhard It can never hurt, and also about those with newlines and other special characters. **I** recognise the problem when `vi` complains, the OP might not.

Comment: Doesn't work if matched files have spaces in their path

Comment: I try it with nano and get redirection not supported

Answer (score 8):

You can use `quickfix` or `errorfile` feature in `vim`:

```
$ grep -n foo * > /tmp/foo.list
$ vim -q /tmp/foo.list
```

Vim will open the first file in `/tmp/foo.list` and place the cursor directly in the line where `foo` was found. You can go to the next instance using `:cn` and previous instance using `:cp`.

**Side note**: If you are already using `vim` or `gvim`, then I would suggest using its inbuilt `grep` functionality. Read `:help vimgrep` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For search in project no need to leave vim with [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)

`autocmd QuickFixCmdPost *grep* cwindow`

Below you can see example of `:Ggrep config`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After reading your comment, I realize I didn't understand the question initially.  Here is a simple script which takes your search term as an argument and prompts for the path to search.  If the result is found in only one file, it opens the file for editing at the location of the search result.

```
#!/bin/bash

SRCHTRM="$1"

read -p "Where to search: " SRCHPATH

FILEFOUND=$(grep "$SRCHTRM" $SRCHPATH)
FILEFOUNDCNT=$(grep "$SRCHTRM" $SRCHPATH | wc -l)

FILEAWK=$(echo "$FILEFOUND" | awk -F":" '{ print $1 }')

if [ "$FILEFOUNDCNT" -eq "1" ];then
    vi +/"$SRCHTRM" "$FILEAWK"
else
    echo "$1 was found in more than one file"
fi
```

Comment: But this seems to allow me to edit the output of grep, but what I want to do is edit the file with the filename that grep returns.

Answer (score 0):

@devnull got the answer right in this comment:

> You were rather close, simply tell vim to read from STDIN:
>
> `grep foo | vim -`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Anthon's answer for a case where you have more than one match, it may be helpful in some cases to use `head -1` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14093511/6605826)) to select only the first result: `vim "$(grep -l STRING FILES|head -1)"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing a long command that has grep somewhere in the middle of it you can also do

```
vim `command1 | grep whatever | awk '{do_something_else}'`
```