# grep for files and open the resultant matches

Tags: grep, find, osx, pipe, xargs

I'm trying to open all files based on some return values from grep in the command line.  I know that I can use the `-l` option to only return filenames, but I would like to combine this somehow with another series of flags or arguments to yield the full paths of said files.

I have tried something like:

```
find . -iname "*.ext" | xargs grep -l "mystring" | xargs open
```

And also something like:

```
grep -HR -l mystring . | xargs open
```

With little success.  Note that I would like to recurse down into all subdirs as well.
I saw [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115591/how-can-i-open-a-file-that-results-from-grep), which doesn't completely relate.

UPDATE:

I was able to get this kind of working with

`grep -HR -l mystring . | xargs -L 1 open`

Problem is that for a lot of the files, the command line complains in two ways:

`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -1712 for the file /Users/blah/blah.ext`

`The files /blah/blah/file.ext do not exist`, where the path has a space in it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have spaces in file names then you need to use `print0` option for file, later `-0` for `xargs`, and lastly `-I {}` for second `xargs`.

```
find . -iname "*.maxpat" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "mystring" | xargs -I '{}' open '{}'
```

Tested with `emacs` as an `open` command.

Answer (score 1):

`-exec` takes the exit status of the command you put in it and uses it logicially within `find`

So, just something simple like this should work

```
find . -iname "*.ext" -exec grep -q "mystring" {} \; -exec open {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of `grep` you are using, but if I'm reading the man page of `grep` correctly, then the scanning will be stopped after the first successful match. Is that what you want? What I understood from your question was that you wanted to "open all files".

If you don't mind using `vim` or `gvim`, then you can use this:

```
$ grep -n mystring *.ext > /tmp/mystring.list
$ vim -q /tmp/mystring.list
```

(I've never tried to combine these two commands since `vim` doesn't read `quickfix` / `errorfile` from `stdin`)

Vim will open the first file in `/tmp/mystring.list` and place the cursor directly in the line where `mystring` was found. You can go to the next instance using `:cn` and previous instance using `:cp`.

If you aren't a `vim` user and since you said the linked question didn't help you much, then `find ... -print0` should help - as already suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Use `pwd` by find:

```
find `pwd` -iname *.maxpat | xargs grep -l "mystring" | xargs open
```